# ContourPlot of a polar flow field (complex function)

Tags: plotting, complex

I am currently trying to contourplot a dimensionless velocity-field given as:

```
W =  1/\[Alpha] Im[Sec[Cos[-(1/2) q I Log[10, (2 \[Alpha] \[CapitalTheta])/q]]/
 Cos[\[Alpha]]] + 1/2 I q Log[10, (2 \[Alpha] \[CapitalTheta])/q]]
```

with

```
\[Alpha] -> \[Pi]/8, q -> 1, a -> 10/10^6
```

and the complex polar coordinate `\[CapitalTheta] -> a R E^(I \[CurlyPhi])`
with `{R, 0, 4/\[Pi]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}`
My problem now is to generate the ContourPlot of the function. I know how the result should look like (at least similar)
[image]

I have already tried a coordinate transformation and much more, but unfortunately that did not work either.

I´d be happy for every bit of support.
Thanks and best regards,
Seb

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

With the proper replacements, I get something different from your solution:

```
W = 1/\[Alpha] Im[
     Sec[Cos[-(1/2) q I Log[10, (2 \[Alpha] \[CapitalTheta])/q]]/
        Cos[\[Alpha]]] + 
      1/2 I q Log[
        10, (2 \[Alpha] \[CapitalTheta])/q]] /. {\[Alpha] -> \[Pi]/8, 
    q -> 1, \[CapitalTheta] -> a R E^(I \[CurlyPhi])} /. {a -> 
    10/10^6};

ContourPlot[W, {R, 0, 4/\[Pi]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey,
without transforming the polar coordinates into cartesian coordinates, I get the same result as you.